# My chat client freezes up after beginning threads

Tags: python, function, sockets, blocking

I made a better chat client following help from people:

They told me that if I didn't want to be blocked on .recv when waiting for messages,          I would need to use threads, classes, functions, and queues to do so.

So I followed some help a specific person gave me where I created a thread from a class and then defined a function that was supposed to read incoming messages and print them.

I also created a function that allows you to enter stuff to be sent off.

Thing is, when I run the program. Nothing happens.

Can somebody help point out what is wrong? (I've asked questions and researched for 3 days, without getting anywhere, so I did try)

```
from socket import *
import threading
import json
import select

print("Client Version 3")
HOST = input("Connect to: ")
PORT = int(input("On port: "))
# Create Socket

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
print("Connected to: ",HOST,)

#-------------------Need 2 threads for handling incoming and outgoing messages--

#       1: Create out_buffer:
Buffer = []

rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select([s],Buffer,[])

class Incoming(threading.Thread):
    # made a function a thread
    def Incoming_messages():
        while True:
            for i in rlist:
                data = i.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    print(data.decode())

# Now for outgoing data.
def Outgoing():
    while True:
        user_input=("Your message: ")
        if user_input is True:
            Buffer += [user_input.encode()]
        for i in wlist:
            s.sendall(Buffer)
            Buffer = []
```

Thanks for taking a look, thanks also to Tony The Lion for suggesting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this revised version of your code: (in python3.3)

```
from socket import *
import threading
import json
import select


print("client")
HOST = input("connect to: ")
PORT = int(input("on port: "))

# create the socket
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
print("connected to:", HOST)

#------------------- need 2 threads for handling incoming and outgoing messages--

#       1: create out_buffer:
out_buffer = []

# for incoming data
def incoming():
    rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select([s], out_buffer, [])
    while 1:
        for i in rlist:
            data = i.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print("\nreceived:", data.decode())

# now for outgoing data
def outgoing():
    global out_buffer
    while 1:
        user_input=input("your message: ")+"\n"
        if user_input:
            out_buffer += [user_input.encode()]
#       for i in wlist:
            s.send(out_buffer[0])
            out_buffer = []

thread_in = threading.Thread(target=incoming, args=())
thread_out = threading.Thread(target=outgoing, args=())
thread_in.start() # this causes the thread to run
thread_out.start()
thread_in.join()  # this waits until the thread has completed
thread_out.join()
```

- in your program you had various problems, namely you need to call the threads; to just define them isn't enough.
- you also had forgot the function input() in the line:            user_input=input("your message: ")+"\n".
- the "select()" function was blocking until you had something to read, so the program didn't arrive to the next sections of the code, so it's better to move it to the reading thread.
- the send function in python doesn't accept a list; in python 3.3 it accepts a group of bytes, as returned by the encoded() function, so that part of the code had to be adapted.

Comment: Thanks, I really had a lot of mistakes, I'll try and use this right away. It's been a real struggle lately getting this to work. Believe it or not I've been at it for 2-3 days without much luck. Your answer means a lot to me, not just another answer with a documentation reference. I'll post any other questions if I have them.

Comment: When I run this, it acts pretty strange. Here's what Happens: I open client # 1: And I connect to the server. I then connect client # 2. (Nothing happens). Next I type something into client 1's 'your message prompt. User 2 does not receive it. However, as soon as client 2 types and sends something, it receives the message. Now the other client doesn't get what Client 2 just sent. And it has to wait for a message to be send before it recieves the message. It looks like now instead of having the .recv blocking us. It appears that the user input stops the process from recieving and prin

Comment: And printing the message. Is there any way to bypass this? Are processes needed?

Comment: I have an idea! How about a timeout!  It could be like (Probably not applicable) time.count(5) or something (count doesn't exist most likely) And then if no input in 5 seconds, it 'refreshes'. It might delete the text, but if we could find a way to stop it from deleting the text